# How to initialize static member when = operator is overridden in c++

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

Please excuse my English.

I did override operator= in my class. Now I am struggling to initialize a static member.

I get:
error: conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'TObj' requested

**My Header File:**

```
#include <mutex>

template<typename T>
class TObj{
private:
    std::mutex m;
public:
    T val;
    // = coperation
     TObj& operator=(const T& rhs){
       m.lock();
       val = rhs;
       m.unlock();
       return *this;
    }

    operator T(){
        m.lock();     // THIS IS A BUG. Thank you Praetorian
        return val;   // RETURNS AND NEVER UNLOCKS
        m.unlock();   // DO NOT USE. Use lock_guard
    }

    ~TObj(){}

};


class OJThread
{
private:


public:
    OJThread();
    virtual void run() = 0;
    void start();
};
```

**My ugly cpp file:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ojthread.h"


using namespace std;

class testThread: OJThread{

public:
    static TObj<int> x;
    int localX;
    testThread(){
        localX = x;
    }

    void run(){
        cout<<"Hello World. This is "<<localX<<"\n";
    }

};

TObj<int> testThread::x = 0;

int main()
{

    testThread myThread;
    testThread myThread2;

    myThread.run();
    myThread2.run();
    return 0;
}
```

I haven't implemented threads yet so please don't worry about that.

I get error at the line:

```
TObj<int> testThread::x = 0;
```

If this member is public and not static, it is no problem to do:

myThread1.x = 0;

Thank you

Comment: You haven't told the compiler how to turn an `int` into a `TObj<int>`, to rephrase the error.

Comment: `operator T(){
        m.lock();
        return val;
        m.unlock();
    }` Your mutex is locked once and never unlocked. Use [`lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) instead of manually locking and unlocking.

Comment: Thank you. I will add comment to indicate that.

Answer (score 7):

You have to implement a constructor which takes `T` as parameter for `TObj`. When you perform a assignment during a object initialization it calls the constructor of the initializing object rather than the `operator=`.

So this

```
TObj<int> testThread::x = 0;
```

is basically the same as

```
TObj<int> testThread::x(0);
```